# Date difference calculation in C# vs Moment.js

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, momentjs

I was doing calculation on two dates. I need to find how much days left for the user to use their contract in the site. I have expiry date stored in the DB. And I need to compare this with the current date and get the remaining days left to enjoy their subscription.

Initially this number of days remaining calculation was in the C#.

```
var daysLeft = Convert.ToInt32((data.expiryDate.Date - DateTime.Now.Date).TotalDays);
//Say, the expiryDate is Thu Dec 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), And daysLeft is 220 for the above statement
```

And Now i tried the same in Moment.js in client side.

```
moment(data.expiryDate).diff(moment(), 'days')
//Say, the expiryDate is Thu Dec 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and it is giving 219.
```

I also tried like subtracting two dates in same format after converting it to YYYY-DD-MM as below which is giving the error

```
moment(data.expiryDate).format('YYYY-DD-MM').diff(moment().format('YYYY-DD-MM'), 'days')
Object doesn't support property or method 'diff'
```

Why in C# its 220 and in moment.js it is 219? Am I missing anything? Please suggest me where the calculation goes wrong.

Comment: Have tried converting to decimal instead of int?

Comment: what is timezone on the server,  time zone on the browser ?

Comment: In browser UTC - chennai, kolkatta, newdelhi. and in DB server (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada

Comment: Javascript `moment()` is date **and time**, am I right? (c# `DateTime.Now.Date` is like `DateTime.Today` which means `00:00:00.000` for time)

Comment: @Rafalon Yup, a) the javascript code has also the time, but the c# code has not (so the js code is wrong) and b) it would be easier to do `DateTime.Today` instead `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: `moment(data.expiryDate).format('YYYY-DD-MM')` returns a string, which doesn't have a *diff* method, hence "Object doesn't support property or method 'diff'".

Answer (score 3):

When you do this in c#:

```
data.expiryDate.Date - DateTime.Now.Date
```

you actually substract **whole days** (because `.Date` results in time being `00:00:00.000`).

Now, you do the Following in js:

```
moment(data.expiryDate).diff(moment(), 'days')
```

and the difference here is that you substract **date & time**.

---

Note (use of `.Now` without `.Date`):

```
var expiryDate = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2020 10:00:00");
Console.WriteLine((expiryDate.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays);
```

returns `219.654703995023` when the same code with `.Date` returns `220`

---

**TL;DR:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|       moment.js       |       C#                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|moment()               | DateTime.Now                        |
|moment().startOf('day')| DateTime.Today (=DateTime.Now.Date) |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want the same result for your javascript part, you should probably use `.startOf('day')` (which seems to be the equivalent of `.Date` according to [Moment.js | Home](https://momentjs.com/))

Answer (score 2):

In C#, TotalDays represents whole and fractional days, the return type is double. And convert to int will round to the nearest 32-bit signed integer.
In moment.js, diff will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer.
But before 2.0.0, diff returned a number rounded to the nearest integer, not a truncated number.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't really matter for c# that it is rounded or not, as we are substracting **days** (note: with time being `00:00:00.000`) so the difference is already a whole number.

Comment: But the days calculated by moment.js is not a integer. It will be truncated.